# Generic object for different JSON with same structure Angular 2

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have problem with JSON data i have 3 table in my base "dictionary" with same structure and different column names:

```
{"id":1,"test_1":"test"},{"id":2,"test_1":"lalala"} - first JSON 


{"id":1,"test_2":"****"},{"id":2,"test_2":"afery-t"} - secound JSON
```

And I want to make one Class in Angular 2

```
 export class dictionary{

   id:number;
   dictValue:string;

}
```

Is it posible to cast this differend JSON object to on like this becouse this not working:

```
res => <dictionary[]>  res.json()
```

And in Html template i have Json object not class value in NgFor.

```
 <tr *ngFor="let item of directoryArray">
{{item.test_1}} - i want to have {{item.dictValue}}
</tr>
```

controller

```
 directoryArray:dictionary[];
this._httpService.getAll().subscribe(
            data => this.directoryArray = data,
            error => alert(error),
            () => console.log("Done"));
```

Thanks for help tell me is it possible or i have to change value in base or make different object for all JSONs.

Comment: Instead of a class, you should use an interface. And this is a Typescript feature, not a JavaScript one. Angular 2 uses TypeScript by default.

Comment: Yes i have changed it thanks

Comment: but this must have all field interface ssda{ test_1: string,test_2: string,}, or just one month: string??

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, use an Interface:

```
export interface dictionary { // I would use 'Dictonary' here
   id:number;
   dictValue:string;
}
```

Not knowing how your `getAll` function looks like, here's an example of getting the "first" JSON:

```
getFirstJSON(): Observable<dictionary[]> {
  return this.http.get('the Url')
    .map(res => res.json().map((x:any) => Object.assign({id:x.id,dictValue:x.test_1})))
}
```

where we use `map` to set the properties to match your interface.

Then in your component:

```
directoryArray: dictionary[];

this.service.getFirstJSON()
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.directoryArray = data;
  })
```

Now we have the properties matching the interface, which can be used in template:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of directoryArray">
  <td>{{item.dictValue}}</td>
</tr>
```